# How to get a Tester API Key for Google Play Games?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Is there any way to get a Google Play Games API key for local testing purposes? (Android) (Similarly that the test key of Google Maps API).

I intend to use some of the Google Play Games APIs mainly for educational purposes (i.e For learning about it..). In the Google Play Services developer console, I tried create a key, but now the Google require a payment as Full Google Play Developer.

..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example tutorial.  Just follow steps 1 - 6 in "Getting Started with Google Applications".  Mine shows an example on getting a key for Google Maps Android API v2, but the entire list of apps is in there including the Google Play Games and other APIs.

[Link:  Getting Started with Google Applications - Google Maps API Example](http://www.digitalopium.com/android-google-maps-api-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot test without a developer account.. You need OAuth 2.0 client id. Game services testing can only be done with the projects which are exported/ran with a particular keystore SHA1 which you given while creating the client id.